# Ir buscar os vários campos à query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, query

Tenho esta querie:

```
@tudo = Isolated.joins("LEFT JOIN resists ON resists.isolated_id = isolateds.id").joins("LEFT JOIN genes ON genes.isolated_id = isolateds.id LEFT JOIN stats ON stats.gene_id = genes.id LEFT JOIN mutations ON mutations.id = stats.mutation_id").all
```

Quero ir buscar campos do model `Gene`, como por exemplo o campo `name`.
Quando faço o @tudo na consola rails (rails c), aparece-me isto:

```
Isolated Load (4.4ms)  SELECT `isolateds`.* FROM `isolateds` LEFT JOIN resists ON resists.isolated_id = isolateds.id LEFT JOIN genes ON genes.isolated_id = isolateds.id LEFT JOIN stats ON stats.gene_id = genes.id LEFT JOIN mutations ON mutations.id = stats.mutation_id
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Isolated id: 1, name: "xpto", disease: "sklhafl", n_samples: 1, origin_id: 1, organism_id: 3, created_at: "2015-03-23 16:21:20", updated_at: "2015-03-23 16:21:20">, #<Isolated id: 2, name: "khjlsdkf", disease: "lkajsçdl", n_samples: 123, origin_id: 1, organism_id: 1, created_at: "2015-03-26 18:57:02", updated_at: "2015-03-26 18:57:02">,...
```

Ou seja, só dados do Isolated, mesmo as tabelas estando juntas.
se fizer `@tudo.select("genes.name")`, na consola do rails dá-me isto:

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Isolated id: nil, name: nil>, #<Isolated id: nil, name: nil>, #<Isolated id: nil, name: nil>, #<Isolated id: nil, name: nil>, #<Isolated id: nil, name: nil>, #<Isolated id: nil, name: nil>, #<Isolated id: nil, name: nil>, #<Isolated id: nil, name: nil>, #<Isolated id: nil, name: nil>, #<Isolated id: nil, name: nil>, ...]>
```

e quando no ficheiro html.erb faço:
`@tudo.gene.name` dá-me erro, como é que posso ir buscar o nome do gene?

Comment: já descobri basta fazer: @tudo = @tudo.select("genes.name as genename")

Comment: Adicione seu comentário em uma pergunta, e a aceite como resposta, pois ela pode ajudar outros usuários com o mesmo problema, ou problemas semelhantes.

Answer (score 1):

já descobri basta fazer: @tudo = @tudo.select("genes.name as genename")

Answer (score 0):

Catarina, da maneira que foi definido, quando chamamos @tudo, o servidor nos responde com uma lista. No caso, ao chamar @tudo.gene é normal que te salte um erro.

Para receber uma lista com os nomes dos genes, você poderia usar o [método map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17731648/how-to-map-over-a-nested-array).

`@tudo.map(&:name)`

O que o método `map` faz é executar o comando que vem depois dos dois pontos (":") para cada um dos itens da sua lista de genes e devolver o resultado sob a forma de um array.

Espero ter ajudado =)